# Angular 9 How to delete a range of objects inside an array having indexes range specified by a user?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, splice

I am trying to remove objects from an array of objects using a user specified indexes. When a user specify a range between `m` and `n`, that's mean that all array having indexes less than `m` or higher then `n`, I want them to be deleted from the array.

I tried the following when (`m=0` and `n=7`):

```
for (const array in this.data) {
  if (parseInt(array) <= 0 || parseInt(array) >7) {
    this.data.splice(parseInt(array))
  }
}
console.log(this.data)
```

And it's working properly, but once I change `m` into 1, all the array is emptied.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j73a94).

Comment: It would be easier if you think about the problem as - what items should remain after the removal? Create a new list of the items that remain `const x = data.slice(m, n)` then assign `this.data = x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is to get the remaining object after deleting. Here **Array.slice** function comes for the rescue.

**Array.slice** does not modify the original array. It just returns a new array of elements which is a subset of the original array.

Array.slice signature

```
arr.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Consider the following array:

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

To get a slice of an array from values [2, 3, 4, 5], we write:

```
var slicedArr = arr.slice(2, 6);
```

Notice that, here, we gave the second argument as 6 and not 5.
After executing the above code, we get the values as:

```
arr // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
slicedArr // [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to Array.splice is the number of elements to remove.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_splice

If not specified it will remove all the elements from the specified index including specified index.